# Apache Django app: ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu

I installed mod_wsgi, and loaded it in apache. 
This is my apache virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysite.localhost
    ServerAlias mysite.localhost

    Alias /static /var/www/mysite/static
    <Directory /var/www/mysite/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/mysite/mysite>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess mysite
    WSGIProcessGroup mysite
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

When I go to mysite.localhost I get:

> ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi

I try to run it from python shell and everything goes well.
I have django installed globally, not just in the virtualenv.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: My default /usr/bin/python is python 3

Comment: Are you sure that mod_wsgi has been compiled for Python 3 as well? For example, on Ubuntu you have to install `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3`.

Comment: Thank you, that is the problem. I  install libapache2-mod-wsgi instead of py3 version. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Apache with Python 3 on Ubuntu, you should install `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3` instead of `libapache2-mod-wsgi`.